# AssertionError: expected undefined to equal while writing unit test to test the REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing 2 unit tests to test the Rest API. However, the first test fails and the second passes.
Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here? I'm new to JavaScript, and Mocha. Thanks!

**test.js**

````
var request = require('request');
const { response } = require('express');

 it('Get Response recieved', function(done){
    request('http://localhost:5000', function(err,res,body) {
        expect(body).to.equal('Welcome !');
        expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        done();
    })
 })


 it('Success status code', function(done){
    request('http://localhost:5000', function(err,res,body) {
        expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        done();
    })
 })```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `res` object from the callback to check the status-code:

```
expect(body).to.equal('Welcome !');
expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
```

Note: the `request`-library is [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request#deprecated), you should consider changing to a different http-library.